# ASP.NET Core Binding Querystring Parameters to a List of a Complex Type

Tags: asp.net-core

I can use array notation to successfully bind querystring values to a parameter that is List where SomeViewModel contains a handful of properties, one of which is an int array.

Below is the controller definition. When I change the first parameter to be FromQuery, however, the complex type parameter is no longer bound.

Any idea where I am missing something?

This works:

```
URL: /booking/search/23?day=2017-05-12&s[0].id=1

[HttpGet("search/{studio_id}")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Search(int studio_id, [FromQuery] DateTime day, [FromQuery] List<ServiceRequest> s)
```

This does not:

```
URL: /booking/search?studio_id=23&day=2017-05-12&s[0].id=1
[HttpGet("search")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Search([FromQuery] int studio_id, [FromQuery] DateTime day, [FromQuery] List<ServiceRequest> s)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use one model with studio_id, day and s properties?

Comment: That is a good idea for a workaround (which I will try - thank you!), though I am still curious as to why the behavior does not appear to match the documentation.